# JavaScript Function that work well on desktop but does not fully function on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html

This JavaScript is to drag and drop an item anywhere on the screen(starting location is random). Also intended to activate a hyperlink on click(Desktop). This should also work to active a hyperlink on tap(mobile). But this is not the case and I am unsure why.

```
var startPosX = 0;
var startPosY = 0;
var isDragging = false;

function setRandomPosition(mydiv) {
    var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenWidth - mydiv.offsetWidth));
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenHeight - mydiv.offsetHeight));

    mydiv.style.left = randomX + 'px';
    mydiv.style.top = randomY + 'px';
}

function startDrag(elmnt, clientX, clientY) {
    startPosX = clientX;
    startPosY = clientY;

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
        var currentY = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
        var deltaX = startPosX - currentX;
        var deltaY = startPosY - currentY;
        startPosX = currentX;
        startPosY = currentY;
        elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - deltaY + 'px';
        elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - deltaX + 'px';
        isDragging = true;
    }

    function stopDrag() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', elementDrag);
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', stopDrag);

        setTimeout(function () {
            isDragging = false;
        }, 100);
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', elementDrag, { passive: false });
    document.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrag);
}

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    elmnt.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        startDrag(elmnt, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    });

    elmnt.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        startDrag(elmnt, touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    });
}

// Call the function to set the random position initially
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    setRandomPosition(divs[i]);
    dragElement(divs[i]);
}

// Add a click event listener to the elements with the href
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv a');
for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
    links[j].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (isDragging) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            console.log("Element was clicked without dragging.");
            // Uncomment the next lines if you want to open the href link when not dragging
            // var href = this.getAttribute('href');
            // if (href) {
            //     window.location.href = href;
            // }
        }
    });
}
```

Tried to change edit the event.listener for mobile but I am still learning JavaScript so Im no expert.

Comment: So, what DOES happen on mobile?

Comment: Working:
initial random positioning , Drag and Drop function
Not Working: 
opening hyperlink on tap/touch

Comment: Well, the code you've posted has the "open hyperlink" part commented out.  Are you sure you're debugging the right version?

Comment: Sorry, copied over wrong, assume that the code is uncommented.